# Prolog - How to limit path length while getting all paths?

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I am trying to find all paths the size or shorter than a given length between 2 nodes in a graph. I'm able to find all paths, but I am having trouble limiting the size of the path.

What I have right now is:

```
path(P1,P2,[P1,P2]):- 
    edge(P1,P2).

path(P1,P2,[P1|Xs]):-
    edge(P1,W),
    path(W,P2,Xs).
```

And this works, how do I limit path size?

Comment: Do you want to limit path length, or are you really trying to avoid loops that lead to paths with redundancy and ultimately lack of program termination? If the latter, then limiting path length isn't the right way to go about it.

Comment: I want all paths with length shorter or equal to the given one, because that's what I need for my problem.

Comment: OK, thank you, that's a bit clearer, but when you say "given one" what does that mean? Are you providing a length? Or are you saying a "given path"?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer. What I intend to do, and the answer below has pretty much got it covered, is something like:

allPaths(Node1, Node2, List, MaxLength)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
limited_path(P1,P2,N,L):-length(L,N1), path(P1,P2,L), N1=<N.

path(P1,P2,[P1,P2]):- 
    edge(P1,P2).

path(P1,P2,[P1|Xs]):-
    edge(P1,W),
    path(W,P2,Xs).
```

and now call `limited_path/4` instead.

Comment: That returns the paths with length equal to the given one. And that solves my problem. Thank you. But how would I go about changing this so that all paths are returned with length equal or shorter than the given one?

Comment: @MiguelFreitas, sorry my fault edited the answer ,hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm just getting started with Prolog and I'm still having trouble thinking in a recursive way. Your help is appreciated.